# Saving Django form displayed on template like {{form.item}}

Tags: django

Django beginner here.
I'm trying to understand something :

In my template if I'm rendering my form like this

```
{{form}}
```

and click my button

```
<button name="button" type="submit" onclick="">Save Form</button>
```

The form is correctly saving.

But if I change the way I'm displaying my form like :

```
{{form.item1}}
{{form.item2}}
{{form.item3}}
```

to be more flexible on my template, it doesn't save anymore.

Is there a way to achieve this ?

template.html

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div id="London" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>London</h3>

        
        {{ form.last_name }} <!-- not saving but if I'm usgin {{form}} it does work -->
        
    <br/>
    </div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Update
</button> <!-- has to remain inside form tag-->

</form>
```

view.py

```
def update_record(request, pk):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        current_record = models_contacts.objects.get(id=pk)
       
        form = forms_contacts(request.POST or None, instance=current_record, pk=pk)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
       
            messages.success(request, "Record Has Been Updated!")
            return redirect('home')
        return render(request, 'update_record.html', {'form':form})
    else:
        messages.success(request, "You Must Be Logged In...")
        return redirect('home')
```

Comment: It shouldn't cause any issue. could you please share working html code and issue html code for further details.

Comment: Added template an view code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found why, thanks to `{{form.errors}}`
I have some fields in `forms.py` that where `required=True` so apparently they MUST be present in the template if I want to save the form (kinda logical).